# Hadoop using MultipleOutputs with EMR JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop, emr

I'm using Hadoop 2.6.5, writing program which makes 3 output files.

When I run local - the program works great and create 3 output files.
When I run it with the EMR this lines crashes - File already exists :O

I understand that it's not the way to use Hadoop with EMR.

I've seen this post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=131036

But I don't have this method: mos.getCollector
And I didn't find any documenation on how to is mos in java with EMR.

This is the code of my Reducer:

```
@Override
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<>(context);
    }
@Override
protected void cleanup(Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mos.close();

}
```

... End of reduce method - writing the results files part (ones, twos and threes)

```
if (keyArr.length == 1) {
              mos.write(key, result, "ones.txt");      
      }
      else if (keyArr.length == 2) {
              mos.write(key, result, "twos.txt"); 
      }
      else {
              mos.write(key, result, "threes.txt"); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

could you upload the exception?
It seems like a read/write concurenncy

Comment: This is the exception:
java.lang.Object
java.lang.Throwable
java.lang.Exception
java.io.IOException
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException

The question is how to use the Multiple Outputs Object in Hadoop with EMR (Because without the EMR it's working great)